# nfs configured - clients cannot connect

Tags: mount, samba, raid, lvm, nfs

I'm trying to get NFS working on my Ubuntu server 14.04 again. It was originally working until last weekend,  but when I tried to configure samba everything went fubar. Now none of my devices can connect with the NFS share.

This is what I added this to my `/etc/exports`:

```
/export/storage 192.168.0.1/24(rw,async,insecure,no_subtree_check)
```

And I added this to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/storage /export/storage none bind 0 0
```

My file permissions for both `/storage` & `/export/storage` are set to 775. I'm running raid5 and created a logical volume that's mounted to `/storage`. When I do `df -h` my logical volume is correctly displayed:

```
/dev/mapper/lvm--raid-storage  511M  3.4M  508M  1%  /storage
```

Read several troubleshooting articles on the web, but everything seems to be configured correctly. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have fixed the problem. Apparently my firewall was acting like a shredder. The solution was:

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables-save
```

Result: established a ssh connection with my server through on of the devices and successfully mounted the nfs share.

A colleague advised me to also slightly change the `/etc/exports` for safety reasons:

```
/export/storage 192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,insecure,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

And later on installed `iptables-persistent` so the changes to my firewall settings remain after reboots. Hope this helps anyone else bumping into a similar problem.